# how to abstract poi functionality

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm looking to implement apache-poi's text extraction and later, summary info functionality in my program. That said, poi uses different libraries for .doc, docx, .xls and .xlsx files.

Wanting to hide this complexity from the function that calls poi, I've made the following class and method which I can call to extract text from any of the 4 doc types:

```
public class DocExtractor {
private WordExtractor w = null;
private XWPFWordExtractor wx = null;
private ExcelExtractor x = null;
private XSSFExcelExtractor xx = null;

public DocExtractor(File f){
      String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(f.toString());
      if (fileExtension.equals("doc")){
          try{
              FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
              HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(is);
              w = new WordExtractor(doc);
          }
            catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
      }
```

...3 more 'ifs' in the constructor

and the method:

```
    public String getText(){
    String text ="";
    if(this.w != null){
        String[] texted = w.getParagraphText(); //for .doc
        text = this.joiner(texted);
    }
```

... yet more 'ifs'

This works, and hides the implementation,

```
  DocExtractor dm = new DocExtractor(doFile);
  text = dm.getText();
```

but I hate all the 'ifs'.
I can't help but think there must be a better, completely different way of doing this, or maybe some polymorphic trickery...

Those private variables are kind of left over from previous attempts at this class so feel free to toss them in whatever soln you suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/)? Tika uses POI to extract text from office files, but does it all in a common way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a very common Java programming problem. It is typically solved using what is known as the Java Factory Design Pattern. The following link has a nice simple explanation of the Factory pattern - http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/factory_pattern.htm

There are many other design patterns that you might find it useful to look at. Reading about them will give you insight into how lots of Java programmers solve commonly occurring problems. The same author explains most of the common design patters at http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/java_design_patterns.htm

Now, as to your specific problem. First of all, the POI authors use the Factory design pattern. For example, look at the following code:

```
Workbook wb1 = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("myXlsFile.xls"));
Workbook wb2 = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("myXlsxFile.xlsx"));
// this prints "wb1 class = org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook"
System.out.println("wb1 class = " + wb1.getClass().getName());
// this prints "wb2 class = org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook"
System.out.println("wb2 class = " + wb2.getClass().getName());
```

So, as a user of POI, you deal with the same Workbook object with the same properties and methods regardless of whether you are processing an xls file or an xlsx file. However, the authors of POI obviously need to have two very different implementations depending on the file type.

How did they do this without having lots of if statements, such as what is in your code? I will redo your example to show you how you might accomplish the same thing.

The first thing you would do is define a DocExtractor class as follows:

```
public abstract class DocExtractor {

    // constructor
    public DocExtractor(File f) {
       poiFile = f;
    }

    // the getText method must be defined by all derived classes
    public abstract String getText();

    // this protected field is visible to all classes which extend DocExtractor
    protected File poiFile;

}
```

The reason I suggest you make DocExtractor abstract is that you do not want code to be able to create a DocExtractor class. The reason you make the getText method abstract is you want to make sure the classes which extend DocExtactor will define their own versions of getText. Hopefully, this reasoning will be become clear as you read on.

You now define what are known as derived classes of DocExtractor (they "extend" DocExtractor). In this example I will define two classes, one for doc files and one for xls files.

```
// this handles doc files
public class DocExtractorDoc extends DocExtractor {

    // constructor
    public class DocExtractorDoc(File f) {
        // this calls the DocExtractor constructor which has common code for all constructors
        super(f);
        // put code specific to the DocExtractorDoc constructor here
    }

    // concrete implementation of the getText method specific to doc files
    public String getText() {
        // getText code for doc files goes here
    }
}

// this handles xls files
public class DocExtractorXls extends DocExtractor {

    // constructor
    public class DocExtractorXls(File f) {
        // this calls the DocExtractor constructor which has common code for all constructors
        super(f);
        // put code specific to the DocExtractorXls constructor here
    }

    // concrete implementation of the getText method specific to xls files
    public String getText() {
        // getText code for xls files goes here
    }
}
```

You now define a DocExtractorFactory class with a single static create method:

```
public class DocExtractorFactory {

    public static DocExtractor create(File f) {
        // create the appropriate DocExtractor derived class based on the file extension
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(f.getName());
        if (extension.equals("doc") {
            return new DocExtractorDoc(f);
        } else if (extension.equals("xls") {
            return new DocExtractorXls(f);
        } else {
            // error handling code here -- perhaps throw an exception
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is some code which uses the above classes

```
// this actually creates a DocExtractorDoc object (but you don't care)
DocExtractor de1 = DocExtractorFactory.create(new File("myDocFile.doc"));
// this actually uses DocExtractorDoc.getText (but again you don't care)
String s1 = de1.getText();
// this actually creates a DocExtractorXls object
DocExtractor de2 = DocExtractorFactory.create(new File("myDocFile.xls"));
// this actually uses DocExtractorXls.getText
String s2 = de2.getText();
```

So, what we have basically accomplished is only having the if statements in one place, the factory create method. And you can obviously create as many DocExtractor derived classes as you need to by simply writing the code for the class and making a simple change to the create method.

Comment: Very clear and easy to follow answer. I'll also look into those links. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, it looks like Apache has that set up with their ExtractorFactory:
(http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/extractor/ExtractorFactory.html)
...which does just what I want. Still, it was a good learning experience.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support text extraction from a wide range of Office file formats, then rather than writing your own wrappers in front, your best bet is to use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/). Apache Tika is a text and metadata extraction toolkit / library / thingy.

To extract text from Microsoft Office files, Tika calls down to Apache POI to have the actual work done. However, it does that all internally, and hides the complexity of the different formats for you. Instead, all you do is hand it a file, Tika works out what it is, what library to call, has the text extraction performed, and gives you back the text.

When using Apache Tika, you can chose to get either plain text, or HTML. Assuming you want plain text (since that's all the low level POI extractors offer), you'd want something like:

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata(); 
metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, "myfile.name");
String text = tika.parseToString(new File("myfile.name"));
```

That's it. No matter if you've got a .xls, a .ppt, or even one of the [many other supported formats](http://tika.apache.org/1.1/formats.html), you'll get back the plain text content.

Comment: I like the answer above, but I may end up going with Tika for the versatility. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

You could abstract the loading of the excel/word/whatever file and the getText parts.

Creating a commune interface for both of these methods, then implementing these two methods for each of your ifs.

```
interface Extractor {
    public void setInputStream(FileInputStream fis);
    public String getText();
}
```

Implementation for Word

```
class ConcreteWordExtractor implements Extractor {
    private WordExtractor w;

    public void setInputStream(FileInputStream fis) {
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fis);
        this.w = new WordExtractor(doc);
    }

    public String getText() {
        String[] texted = this.w.getParagraphText();
        // rest of your logic for word
    }
}
```

Implementation for Excel

```
class ConcreteExcelExtractor implements Extractor {
    private ExcelExtractor x;

    public void setInputStream(FileInputStream fis) {
        // load the Excel workbook from input stream
        this.x = new ExcelExtractor(...);
    }

    public String getText() {
        // your logic for Excel
    }
}
```

The Doc Extractor, making use of the previous implementations

```
public class DocExtractor {
    private final Extractor extractor;
    // you could use spring or any injector to create this and avoit it being in your code
    private final Map<String, Extractor> extractors = new HashMap<String, Extractor>() {{
            put("doc", new ConcreteWordExtractor());
            put("xls", new ConcreteExcelExtractor());
    }};

    public DocExtractor(File f) {
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(f.getName());
        if (!this.extractors.containsKey(extension))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such extractor for extension `" + extension + "`.");
        this.extractor = this.extractors.get(extension);
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            extractor.setInputStream(fis);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do what you want
        }
    }

    public String getText() {
        return extractor.getText();
    }
}
```

This way you abstract the loading of the file for each format and the text retrieval part, when you will need to support a new format you will have to implement the `Extractor` interface and add it to the map, or as suggested in the comment, you could use any dependency injection library/framework such as Spring to extract that from your code.